# Is it safer to double hash passwords with salt? (a little more complicated)

Tags: javascript, security, password-hash

In this case one wants to authenticate a user via http/s.

In the registration progress the server generates a salt. This salt is send to the user. He then procedes to hash his password with the salt via js and send it to the server. 
There the hash get salted again with the same salt and the twice hashed and salted password gets written into a db with the cleartext salt.

If one tries to authenticate he sends his username, gets the salt and hashes the password. This is send to the server who hash it again and if the saved hash and this is the same the user is authenticated.

I was wondering because of the recent heartbleed bug it would be nice to never expose the real password. But I've read that double hashing can increase the risk of collissions.

Is the way I imagined that the safest way or do I get soimething wrong?

Comment: Do not make up your own cryptographic protocols. Why are you hashing on the client?

Comment: The Heartbleed bug is for OpenSSL, in other words totally encrypted HTTPS transmissions, and look how safe that was. Clientside hashing and salting is in my opinion as useful as ... I couldn't even come up with anything as useless as clientside hashing, it just makes no sense ?

Comment: you use salt to prevent an table brute force in case of an attacker find the hashed passwords saved on the server

Comment: Remember that whatever you do client side is visible client side...

Comment: I wanted to use clientside hashing in case someone breaks into the website and modifies the code to save cleartext passwords. Also in case someone can overtake a https session through a faked cert or the user is dumb enough to click "ignore the risk". I know that may sound paranoid but if I can make the safest way to authenticate why shouldn't i use it. Thats basicalle the idea I had in case i haven't missed out something.

Comment: @user3334690 do you mean the exposed salt? could that be exploited?

Comment: I don't agree with people saying that client-side hashing is useless. 
Sure it doesn't do anything to prevent attackers logging into your website. What it does, however, is it hides the user's password to attackers that gain access to your database. In the worst case, they may be able to retrieve the salted hash of the user password, not the password itself, which is likely reused in several other places by the user. So that's a good thing.

Comment: @mate well the only real benefit I see to doing something like that is to obfuscate things on a network level... but the process you use to salt it on the client, the salt, the salted password, and the username are all then unobfuscated on the network level... anyone dedicated enough could rather easily undo the salt...  I don't think it is a bad thing to do, just that it might not really have a huge benefit, particularly if you are using https... not to mention if they've gotten as far as getting the username and salted password that's already enough to authenticate with.

Comment: **DO NOT ROLL YOUR OWN "CLEVER" PASSWORD HASHING SCHEME!** Find whatever best practice exists for your *server-side* language and follow it.  Chances are it's bcrypt.

Comment: I would never try to create my own hashing algorithm. I would use sha 256 or 512

Answer (score 1):

"In the registration progress the server generates a salt. This salt is send to the user. He-" I'm going to have to stop you right there.

In principle, there is nothing wrong with client-side hashing, as long as you understand that it doesn't increase the security of your system. However, hashing/digesting does mean passwords received are always of a very specific form, regardless of the shape of the actual password the user chose, and it means you (as a server owner) don't theoretically know the password of the user that's sending it to you.

It's not secure, because you -and anyone listening in- can take that hashed password and crack it (because you're no different from an attacker in that respect). However, it does add a layer of trust: "I have to go out of my way to find out what your password is".

Taking that into account, salting at the client isn't useful, and if you get the salt from the server, is a false sense of security: if you are sending the salt from the server to the client, anything that can see the user's password client-side can also see the salt client-side. You might as well write the salting value as an `<h1>` title on the page, there is no security there, and you're just going to waste processor time salting.

Now, you still want to hash properly on the server, with salt, but there is no point in having the client do any salting. Simply give them a client-side digester/hasher (like a SHA256 library) and leave it at that. Then on the server, you receive the password, validate it against what you know about what hashed passwords should look like (right length? no characters outside the hashing space? etc) and then you hash that input with your own salt and store that/use that to validate against your user database.

Comment: Why would you say it is bad to expose the salt to the client? I thought the reason to salt is to prevent rainbow-table attacks. Also in the case someone hacked the db he would also has the salt.
"validate it against what you know about what hashed passwords should look like" why is that important?

Comment: did you read my actual text? Sending the salt from the server to the client makes the salt useless, because anyone can get it. Salt that is public knowledge is not salt. Just time wasted.

Comment: How should it be a disagvantage if everyone does know the salt?
Without the password/hash it is useless and if one can steal that, one can also get the salt. But if there is no salt one can use much faster rainbow-table attacks

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The purpose of a salt has nothing to do with secrecy.  A salt need not be secret, it need only be unique.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering because of the recent heart bleed bug it would be nice to never expose the real password.

I can see where you're coming from, but you haven't thought this all the way through. If you hash the password client side and send the hash to the server, then this hash is essentially the user's password. If an attacker were to gain possession of this hash that the client sent to the server, whether it be through heartbleeding, MITM attacks or otherwise, all the attacker has to do is send this hashed password to your server (without hashing it again client side obviously) in order to log in. Hashing it client side gains you nothing.

> But I've read that double hashing can increase the risk of collisions.

*Theoretically* yes. If the password is longer than the resulting hash, the entropy of the input is guaranteed to be reduced. Even with input shorter than the resulting hash, chances are that the entropy is reduced somewhat. Hashing this reduced entropy data again reduces entropy further (theoretically). In practice this will hardly matter at all.

Comment: If you were ONLY trying to *mitigate* the leaks caused by not patching openssl you *might* do something towards that by running the password through a cipher of some sort on the client and then undoing that cipher server-side... but that would just be silly because you should have patched openssl by now... and that would just make it slightly less likely that a password and username would show up together in the memory dump from the heartbleed bug... also the cipher would be clearly visible on the client so it still is somewhat of a moot point...

Comment: Of course openssl is up to date. 
Yes, that would be the user password, but nobody could reconstruct the real one. So if the user uses his password across the web it wouldn't be compromised.
And good to know that double hashing doesn't compromise the hashes, thanks.

Comment: @mate Alright, I'll give you that it would protect passwords on *other* sites in certain specific scenarios, which is a good stance to take. However I'd also say the only real thing it protects against is heartbleed; all other attack scenarios have other ways to leak the actual plaintext password, especially MITM attacks. And you should protect against heartbleed by having a non-vulnerable OpenSSL version; so doing all this just for passwords is pretty superfluous.